# Float Corruption when Acessing/Reading Values (Cout printing)

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, floating-point, corruption

So, I'm currently working on an OpenGL C++ project, in which I try to load a custom format that I made myself, the only problem is that a single
`cout` statement could ruin the whole thing.

---

All the code needed to understand the problem is here:

```
    for (int i = vertpos; i<vertpos+vertsize; i++) {
        vertices[i] = stof(contents[i]);
    }
```

This code turns strings parsed from a text file (contents = file information) to the vertices float array (or GLfloat, same thing happens).

Vertpos is the position where the vertex information starts (so after header), and vertsize is the size of the information before moving on to my elements table.
Everything works as intended, here's a picture of the model being render

---

**PLEASE** Keep in mind the program is incomplete, so the models have weird shapes due to RGB values and UV values not being set properly (Some other values that are used by the program to determine texture placement and vertex coloring):
[image: Picture of broken model working as intended]

---

Now, lets try adding a small print function, so I can see the values:

```
    for (int i = vertpos; i<vertpos+vertsize; i++) {
        vertices[i] = stof(contents[i]);
        cout << vertices[i] << flush;
    }
```

[image: Picture of broken model working as intended with cout << vertices[i] << flush;]
Everything is **OK!**. Although I would like to separate everything, lets try adding a colon separator:

```
    for (int i = vertpos; i<vertpos+vertsize; i++) {
        vertices[i] = stof(contents[i]);
        cout << vertices[i] << ":separatorstring,anyseparatorgivesthesameresult::::" << flush;
    }
```

[image: Broken Model acting, well, broken (not supposed to)]

---

This seems to trigger ***At random intervals***, while I was writing this, nothing happened once i changed the code, but then tampering with the code that prints the elements (connections between elements table), it just happened again.

I'm struggling to find people having the same experience online, which is weird.
It seems to just, happen.

---

Any inconsistency between pictures (like 1 and 2) which are small are caused because of the rotating model, I try to take the picture at the exact time it rotates, and looking at the values they are the same.

Comment: Please verify that doing a full rebuild without the cout always gives you the same results. Please also verify that adding code somewhere else (unrelated, but in the same function) always gives you the same exact results. 

If you look carefully, you see that all your triangles are different, so I'm suspecting that they are different in every build.

Comment: @lionkor I'm extremely sorry I forgot to mention that the model is constantly rotating, models from picture 1 & 2 are virtually the same.

Comment: so you have verified that it stays the same if you do a full rebuild (as you expect) and only gives you this weird behavior when you add the cout?

Comment: @lionkor Indeed

Comment: picture 3 also just looks rotated, no?

Comment: Yes, but the model zooms out to the side to infinity (basically), I'll add a picture real quick

Comment: Code that changes at random when you change the code usually means: either some variable is uninitialized (and changing the code changes which memory location it goes to, which changes the default value it gets)  OR you are accessing memory you didn't allocate (and it overlaps some other piece of memory, and the overlap can change randomly when you change the code)

Comment: It happens very randomly, I didn't modify the code at all right now and it was different (It had the cout of course)

Comment: Yeah, as user253751 said, check that everything you're using is initialized, but also, if you're threading anything at all (which I wouldn't believe you are), this could also be a race condition. I'm saying this, because if a cout changes the behavior, that's usually a giveaway of a race condition.

Comment: Yeah that's about right, just in case I'll rewrite the whole code, as I never got to clean it up anyways and looks like a dumpster fire.